# Changing tick label line spacing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, latex

I have a quite cluttered plot with y-ticklabels that need to be very long. I've resorted into wrapping them into multiline text with `textwrap`. However that makes the labels overlap (or at least come too close), between categories.

*I can't solve it by spacing the ticks, making the graph larger, changing font or making the text smaller.* (I've already pushed these limits)

As I see it, I could resolve and make it work if I could adjust the line spacing/height to be less than what the font requests.

So imagine for simplicity's sake the following tick-label desperately needs shorter line distance between lines/line height:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.barh(0.75, 10, height=0.5)
plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.yticks([1], ["A very long label\nbroken into 2 line"])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)
plt.show()
```

I've checked `plt.tick_params()` the `rcParams` without finding any obvious solution. I'm using **latex** to format the text, but trying to use `\hspace(0.5em}` in the tick label string seemed not to work/only make things worse.

Any suggestion as to how the line spacing can be decreased would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `linespacing` keyword in your `plt.yticks` line. For example:

```
plt.yticks([1], ["A very long label\nbroken into 2 line"],linespacing=0.5)
```

You can play with the exact value of `linespacing` to fit your needs. Hope that helps.

Here's the original output of your code:
[image: default line spacing]

And here it is with a linespacing of 0.5:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Attempt using this:

```
pylab.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']='???'
```

Mess around with the ??? value to get something you like. You could also try (sing the OO interface):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
ax.set_yticks([1], ["A very long label\nbroken into 2 line"], linespacing=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The `labelsize` command will change the size of your font.

Use a combination of the above with the `rcparams` setup.